# WPF, ComboxBox.ItemTemplate запрет установки выбранного элемента

Tags: wpf, xaml

Делаю ComboBox, в котором задаю ItemTemplate. Просто устанавливаю в Template CheckBox.

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource}">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

Если раскрыть данный ComboBox и кликнуть непосредственно по CheckBox, то устанавливается галочка, ComboBox не закрывается, в текущий выбранный элемент ComboBox ничего не устанавливается, все хорошо (требуемое поведение). Если же кликнуть по элементу ComboBox-а (не затрагивая CheckBox), то сам CheckBox устанавливается в текущий выбранный элемент ComboBox и ComboBox закрывается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как устранить второй вариант поведения? Нужно чтобы при клике только устанавливались или снимались галочки для CheckBox-ов, а в сам ComboBox ничего не устанавливалось. Установку текста в ComboBox планирую обрабатывать отдельно через задания свойства Text.

Дополнение. Получается, что CheckBox-ы не занимают все доступное им пространство. Если, например, сделать так:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

то при клике внутри красной границы устанавливается/снимается галочка (первое поведение). Если вне вне границы, то устанавливается элемент в ComboBox (второе поведение). Установка в Stretch различный параметров выравнивания ничего не меняет.

Comment: Можно попробовать подавить проваливание события клика дальше в `ComboBoxItem`: `e.Handled = true`

Comment: Можно сделать обработку SelectionChanged для ComboBox  с установкой e.Handled = true. Но это никак не меняет поведение.

Comment: Нет, не в `SelectionChanged`, а в `MouseDown` или типа того надо

Comment: Ну или попробуйте установить в `ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle` стиль для `ComboBoxItem` с `HorizontalContentAlignment=Stretch` и `VerticalContentAlignment=Stretch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе, такая разметка решает проблему:

```
<ComboBox Text="Text" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,35,8,8">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,0"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>
```

Единственная проблемка, для того чтобы сделать слева от CheckBox-ов отступ пришлось установить Margin у ComboBoxItem. И из-за этого при наведении на элемент срабатывает подсветка с таким же отступом. Немного некрасиво, но не критично.